# Calendar integration to Domino (Lotus Notes)?

Tags: lotus, lotus-domino

How do I integrate with a Lotus Notes Domino server? I know there are several versions and the answer would be different for each one, but advice on any version would be great at the moment as I haven't gotten the info on what server it is I'm supposed to integrate with yet. Assume version 6+.

I'm assuming I need to do the integration with the server and not the local Lotus Notes client, but that might not be correct?

I need to both read and write to the calendar appointments of a select number of users.
For instance I should be able to create/update/delete a appointment for a certain user.
The appointments are the only thing I need access to, at the moment I have no need for the mails.

From what I have read on the internet there are no standard interface to do this?

1. Should I develop a Domino app that does what I want?
2. Maybe there is a server API that I can use to connect and retrive information?
3. Hopefully this can be done in c#? If not what is the preferred way? I read something about java and that is doable also.

If you don't have any concrete answers but you have useful links, please post those as *comments*.

Comment: Integrate what with Lotus Domino?

Comment: I will need to integrate the calendar appointments from Notes into our own application. In our application you should be able to create appointments that then can be exported/synchronized with the appointments in Notes, and the same thing from Notes to our application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to do this without the pain of having to write code is to use ICal. You will enter all sorts of issues with access, reading appointments etc that are best left to Domino to handle.

There are some good documents on the web on ICal support in Domino.

Answer (score 2):

I have used Java and the C++ APIs to read a Domino calendar.  Depending on the scenario, a server side solution can run into trouble if you want to do more than read -- the workflow sometimes needs the Notes client.  Need to understand more about what you intend to do.

API documentation:
http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/lotus/downloads/toolkits.html

Comment: What i need is the appointments from notes. In our application we can then manipulate those appointments (or create new) that will be exported/synchronized with the appointments in lotus notes. In other words...your should be able to create/edit/delete appointments in both our application and in Notes and they should all be syncronized.

Answer (score 2):

I'd use Java.
Here's Domino Designer help section on Java:
http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/domhelp/v8r0/topic/com.ibm.designer.domino.main.doc/H_9_CODING_GUIDELINES_JAVA.html?resultof=%22%6a%61%76%61%22%20
First read [Running a Java program section](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/domhelp/v8r0/topic/com.ibm.designer.domino.main.doc/H_COMPILING_AND_RUNNING_JAVA.html).
Then you'll be interested in [Accessing databases](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/domhelp/v8r0/topic/com.ibm.designer.domino.main.doc/H_WAYS_TO_ACCESS_NOTES_DATABASES_JAVA.html) link.

Here's example of how to access user's mail db (calendar items are inside mail db in Lotus):
http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/domhelp/v8r0/topic/com.ibm.designer.domino.main.doc/H_EXAMPLES_OPENMAIL_METHOD_JAVA.html

Answer (score 2):

[GooCalSync (openntf](http://openntf.org/projects/pmt.nsf/ProjectLookup/GooCalSync) and [LotusNotes-Google Calendar Synchronizer (sourceforce)](http://sourceforge.net/projects/lngooglecalsync/) are great examples of how to do this in Java.

Answer (score 0):

I've done this before for a CRM product (clearc2.com). iCal is easy, but if you want to do more than insert items and actually do a bi-directional sync to the calendars (which are mail databases on a domino server), then I would look at the appendix of the Lotus Notes C API first. There is a section that explains the C&S piece fairly well. You do not need to use the C API to do the work, but it will explain what the many c&s items (fields) are for.

Click [here](http://www-12.lotus.com/ldd/doc/tools/c/8.5.2/api852ug.nsf/85255d56004d2bfd85255b1800631684/8a3a2d71b95e09bd85256559005ce7b3?OpenDocument) for documentation.

My advice is to keep it simple, e.g. do not try to tackle repeating items (appts/tasks) on the first attempt. And try not to re-use any custom product objects you find in the mail template. These are undocumented Notes classes and can go away anytime. Furthermore, they may not work the same from each point release or even incremental release. The mail template code can be evil.