# How can i use lotus note calendar view in my android app

Tags: android, lotus-notes, lotus-domino

i want to developer an app,i need to use the lotus note calendar in my app,but i don't know the calendar's API,so i need help,thanks.

Comment: This might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5459770/calendar-integration-to-domino-lotus-notes

Answer (score 1):

There are many APIs available for accessing Lotus Notes data. From an Android app, you'll probably want to look into using [Domino Access Services](https://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/ddwiki.nsf/xpAPIViewer.xsp?lookupName=IBM%20Domino%20Access%20Services%209.0.1#action=openDocument&res_title=Domino_calendar_service_reference&content=apicontent), which is a REST API and it includes a service specifically designed for calendar access. Most of the other APIs are general-purpose and therefore require a little bit more knowledge of core concepts from Notes and Domino development.  Note, however, that Domino Access Services is only available with for more recent versions of the Domino server, so if you're dealing with an organization that hasn't upgraded in the last 5 to 10 years, you'll be out of luck.